# Representation on Hilbert space of the product of two symmetry transformations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, operators, hilbert-space

We know by Wigner's theorem that the representation of a symmetry transformation on the Hilbert space is either unitary and linear, or anti-unitary and anti-linear.

Let $T$ and $S$ be two symmetry transformations. Let $U(T)$ and $U(S)$ be the representations of these transformations. What can we say about unitarity or anti-unitarity of $U(TS)$ if we know the unitarity or anti-unitarity of U(T) and $U(S)$? Why?

Comment: It seems pretty straightforward to me.  For an anti-unitary operator $U$ we have $(U \psi, U \chi) = (\psi, \chi)^*$.  Then for a product $U V$ of two unitary operators we have $(U V \psi, U V \chi) = (\psi, \chi)$, which means the product $U V$ is unitary.  The other cases can be worked out similarly.

Comment: But U(TS) is in general not equal to U(T)U(S). If it would have been, your argument would have worked.

Comment: $U(TS) = U(T)U(S)$, that's part of the definition of a representation.  Do you have a counterexample where this is not true?

Comment: @Sidious Lord: Yes, e.g. [projective representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_representation).

Comment: @Qmechanic OK, but when we have projective representations, don't we pass to the covering group or add central extensions such that we always have an honest to God representation?  I thought there are no obstructions to doing that in relevant physical applications, but I would be interested to know if this is not true.

Comment: @Sidious Lord: In my interpretation of OP's question(v1), in order to be as general as possible, the word _representation_ should not necessarily be understood as implying any group structure or group representation (projective or not), cf. my answer.

Comment: @Qmechanic The word representation in math means isomorphism between one object and another. If the group structure is not preserved, it is not a representation. I agree that projective representations should be also taken into account, but due to slightly different reasoning. Formally, by the way, $U(TS)=U(T)U(S)$ holds for projective representations. Equality in projective spaces and the way they usually explained may confuse, but the group structure is preserved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I) [Wigner's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem) states that a symmetry operation $S: H \to H$ is a unitary or [anti-unitary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiunitary_operator)$^{1}$ operator $U(S)$ up to a phase factor $\varphi(S,x)$,

$$ S(x)~=~ \varphi(S,x)\cdot U(S)(x), \qquad x~\in~H,\qquad \varphi(S,x)~\in~\mathbb{C} ,\qquad |\varphi(S,x)|~=~1 .$$

In this context, a *symmetry operation* $S$ is by definition a surjective (not necessarily linear!) map $S: H \to H$ such that

$$|\langle S(x),S(y)\rangle|~=~|\langle x,y\rangle|,\qquad\qquad x,y~\in~H.$$

Let us introduce the terminology that a symmetry operation $S$ is of *unitary (anti-unitary) type* if there exists a unitary (an anti-unitary) $U(S)$, respectively.

Moreover, if ${\rm dim}_{\mathbb{C}} H \geq 2$, then one may show that

1. $U(S)$ is unique up to a *constant* phase factor, and
2. $S$ cannot have both a unitary and an antiunitary $U(S)$. In other words, $S$ cannot  both be of unitary and anti-unitary type.

II) It follows by straightforwardly applying the definitions, that the composition $S \circ T$ of two symmetry operations $S$ and $T$ is again a symmetry operation, and it is even possible to choose

$$ U(S \circ T)~:=~U(S) \circ U(T).$$
Finally, in the case ${\rm dim}_{\mathbb{C}} H \geq 2$,

1. $S \circ T$ is of anti-unitary type, if precisely one of $S$ and $T$ are of anti-unitary type, and
2. $S \circ T$ is of unitary type, if zero or two of $S$ and $T$ are of anti-unitary type.

Reference:

1. V. Bargmann, *Note on Wigner's Theorem on Symmetry Operations,* J. Math. Phys. 5 (1964) 862. Here is a [link](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~henri105/Teaching/CFTclass-Bar64.pdf) to the pdf file.

--

$^{1}$ We use for convenience a terminology where linearity (anti-linearity) of $U(S)$ are implicitly implied by the definition of $U(S)$ being unitary (anti-unitary), respectively.

Comment: Further references: 2. S. Weinberg, _Quantum Theory of Fields,_ Vol. 1; Appendix 2.A, p. 91. 3. https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3624 . 4. https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.0779 . 5. https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.2133 .

Comment: I plan an update.